# Is it bad practice to implement a graph's nodes as a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am attempting to implement a graph in C++ where each node is an instance of `class A`. My first instinct was to represent the collection of nodes in a `Graph` object by a vector of objects of type `A`.

However, I wanted to implement the following functionality as well: Suppose I overload the `+` operator so that when `g_2 = g_0 + g_1` (where the `g`'s are instances of the Graph class), `g_2`'s nodes consist of the combined nodes of `g_0` and `g_1`. If I modify any of the nodes in `g_2`, `g_0` and `g_1`'s nodes will remain unchanged and in a certain sense `g_2` will no longer remain the sum of `g_0` and `g_1`. However, if I instead represent the nodes in a graph as a vector of *pointers* to objects of type `A`, then modifying `g_2` will modify `g_0` and `g_1`, and vice versa, which would be desirable for the project I am working on.

That being said, I can't help but suspect that having a vector of pointers as a data member is dangerous,  but I don't know enough to really say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector of pointers is fine. You just need to take care of the memory management of your objects yourself, but this is definitely doable.

You will need to allocate your objects with `new A()` and delete them with `delete pointer_to_a` if you want to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why would I need to allocate my objects with `new A()`?

Comment: My point was that no matter whether you use ordinary pointers or smart pointers of any kind, you should allocate your objects on the heap in some way, for example using new. You may of course also have pointers to global objects in your vector. Pointers to local variables in your current function would only work until you leave that function. It is best not to mix the allocation strategies, since eventually you want to free all your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Having vector of pointers is fine. I think is a common practice.

It won't be hard or dangerous if you use smart pointers like shared_ptr.

`typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;
 std::vector<A_ptr> nodes;`

It will take care of memory managment.

Comment: Careful with the shared_prt. Cycles in graphs are all too common.

Comment: @user4581301 Why would cycles in a graph cause issues with `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Shared pointer `delete`s it's contents when there are no more references to it. With a cycle the loop in the references prevents deletion even if the cycle is cut off from the rest of the graph.

Comment: @Cycle discussion: Which then leads into the dark dungeons of garbage collectors. Reference counting (shared_ptr) is a solution in _some_ situations, not all.